# Monthly OTA update

Tags: ota-update

When the monthly security OTA update is being applied, does the android system verify the integrity of the system partitions and system apps ?

Comment: I suggest you consider visiting our [ask] guide to know how to ask a good question. A good question shows effort on part of the asker to solve the problem on their own. Your questions consistently shows no efforts so far in that regard. For example, if you look for an answer for this question you would easily find one through a search engine. If you still don't understand what you find, let us know. We can help you out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends. If it is an incremental update, then yes, it does check vendor, system, boot and other partitions to pass an integrity check before applying an update.
On the other hand, if it is a full update (1.5GB or so) then it will overwrite the main partitions and hence won't need an integrity pass.